# How to move "Show Applications" button from bottom to top in launcher?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I want to move that button from bottom to top in launcher as was in unity. How can I do so?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This command will move it to the top:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top true`

Use this to undo it:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top false`

These commands can also be used to move the "Show Applications" button in dock from right to left or vice versa.

Comment: I used this command to move this button from right to left corner of my dock which I positioned at the bottom of my desktop.

Comment: I think this option should really be available through the gui as well.